# When Service runs,all networks are to be disable

Tags: android

I am doing an apps, that "When Service starts to run at the background, all networks(Bluetooth,wifi etc) should get disable and when i stop the service it should get enable. I dont know how to use it in Service.

Comment: This is going to annoy your users - when your service is running you want to stop users being able to user their network connections? why?

Comment: Thanks 4 ur reply..s..Bcause  apps product should be secure and should not get transfered in any networks.I done an apps that when first button is clicked, remaining buttons are visible..At the same time Service begins 2 run. so when stop the service,user couldnt view the remaining hidden buttons.So my question is, when Service runs, the user should not able 2 access any network..if user tries 2 switch on network, some toast msg should display like ,"Please stop the service to activate network".is it possible?